# Generate a progressive number when new record are inserted (some record need to have the same number)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, data-pipeline

the Title can be a little confused. Let me explain the problem. I have a pipeline that loads new record daily. This record contain sales. The key is <date, location, ticket, line>. This data are loaded into a redshift table and than are exposed through a view that is read by a system. This system have a limit, the column for the ticket is a varchar(10) but the ticket is a string of 30 char. If the system take only the first 10 character will generate duplicate. The ticket number can be a "fake" number. Doesn't matter if it isn't equal to the real number. So I'm thinking to add a new column on the redshift table that contain a progressive number. The problem is that I cannot use an identity column because the record belonging to the same ticket must have the same "progressive number". Then I will expose this new column (ticket_id) instead of the original one.

That is what I want:

| day | location | ticket | line | amount | ticket_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/12/2020 | 67 | 123...GH | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 12/12/2020 | 67 | 123...GH | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 12/12/2020 | 67 | 123...GH | 3 | 23 | 1 |
| 12/12/2020 | 23 | 123...GB | 1 | 13 | 2 |
| 12/12/2020 | 23 | 123...GB | 2 | 45 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 12/12/2020 | 78 | 123...AG | 5 | 100 | 153 |

The next day when new data will be loaded I want start with the ticket_id 154 and so on.

Each row have a column which specify the instant in which it was inserted. Rows inserted the same day have the same insert_time.

My solution is:

1. insert the record with ticket_id as a dense_rank. But each time (that I load new record, so each day) the ticket_id start by one, so...
2. ... update the rows just inserted as ticket_id = ticket_id + the max number that I find under the ticket_id column where insert_time != max(insert_time)

Do you think that there is a better solution? It would be very nice if a hash function existed that take <day, location, ticket> as input and return a number of max 10 characters.

Comment: It seems like you should fix the data model so the correct length of the original ticket is stored.

Comment: Generating custom sequential identifier is a common topic. However, no idea how this would be programmed in Redshift (I've done it with VBA). Otherwise, calculate the sequence in query when needed.

Comment: Gordon, the system that stored these data doesn't want change his model

Answer (score 0):

So from the comments it sounds like you cannot add a dimension table to just look up the number or 10 character string that identifies each ticket as this would be a data model change.  This is likely the best and most accurate way to do this.

You asked about a hash function to do this and there are several.  But first let's talk about hashes - these take strings of varying length and make a signature out of them.  Since this process can significantly reduce the number of characters there is a possibility that 2 different string will generate the same hash.  The longer the hash value is the lower the odds are for having such a collision but the odds are never zero.  Since you can only have 10 chars this sets the odds of a hash collision.

The md5() function on Redshift will take a string and make a 32 character string (base 16 characters) out of it.  md5(day::text || location || ticket:text) will make such a hash out of the columns you mentioned.  This process can make 16^32 possible different strings which is a big number.

But you only want a string of 10 character.  The good news is that hash functions like md5() spread the differences between strings across the whole output so you can just pick any 10 characters to use.  Doing this will reduce the number of unique values to 16^10 or about 1.1 trillion - still a big number but if you have billions of rows you could see a collision.  One way to improve this would be to base64 encode the md5() output and then truncate to 10 characters.  Doing this will require a UDF but would improve the number of possible hashes to 1.1E18 - a million times larger. If you want the output to be an integer you can convert hex strings to integers with strtol() but a 10 digit number only has 10 billion possible values.

So if you are sure you want to use a hash this is quite possible.  Just remember what a hash does.